# how to get session and insert data to DB then remove session

Tags: php, session, switch-statement

i want to insert data from the table product to the database idk how it does

otherwise i have to send it by button or form?

index.php

```
if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
switch($_GET["action"]) {
     case "save":
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
             
      <!-- can i add insert sql immediately or i have to do something before this -->
      <!-- HERE! i want to insert when get session from button BtnSave
                 then remove session   -->             
            }
        }
    break;
------------------------
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])){
    $total_quantity = 0;
    $total_price = 0;
?>  

<?php       
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
        $item_price = $item["quantity"]*$item["price"];
        ?>
                <tr>
                <td><img src="<?php echo $item["image"]; ?>" class="cart-item-image" /><?php echo $item["name"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item["code"]; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $item["quantity"]; ?></td>
                <td  style="text-align:right;"><?php echo "$ ".$item["price"]; ?></td>
                <td  style="text-align:right;"><?php echo "$ ". number_format($item_price,2); ?></td>
               
                </tr>
                <?php
                $total_quantity += $item["quantity"];
                $total_price += ($item["price"]*$item["quantity"]);
        }
        ?>
    <td colspan="5"><a id="BtnSave" href="index.php?action=save&code=<?=$item["code"];?>">Save!</a> </td>
```

i tried to insert that the result  is able to add to the database

the only last one that i clicked and i want to get the whole things in the cart

can you explain me or some example that can help me to get the answer

Comment: The button is outside the foreach loop so it only gets the last value of $item. If you want to get all the values you'd be better with a form and several hidden fields.

Comment: okay, i got it and how to get session this code is correct or i have to add something additionally, action=save&code=$itemcode  is sent that is enough?